# Why OffsetDateTime serializations/deserialization results have difference?

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson, offsetdatetime

I have follows object:

```
@Validated
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Schema(description = "Request")
public final class Request implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("date")
    @Schema(description = "Date")
    private OffsetDateTime date;
}
```

And i send this object as rest-controller's response:

```
@RestController
public class RequestController {

    @RequestMapping(
        value = "/requests",
        produces = {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, 
        consumes = {"application/json"},
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Request> get() {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.OCTOBER, 22);
        OffsetDateTime dateTime = date.atTime(OffsetTime.MAX);
        Request request = new Request(dateTime);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(request);
    }
}
```

Yet i have configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements ServletContextInitializer, WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final List<FilterRegistration> filterRegistrations;
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public WebConfiguration(List<RestApplicationInstaller> restApplicationInstallers,
                            List<MonitoringRestApplicationInstaller> monitoringRestApplicationInstallers,
                            List<FilterRegistration> filterRegistrations,
                            ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.filterRegistrations = filterRegistrations;
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        VersionServletInstaller.installServlets(servletContext, getRegisterAsyncService(servletContext));
        filterRegistrations.forEach(filterRegistration -> filterRegistration.onApplicationEvent(new ContextRefreshedEvent(applicationContext)));
    }

    private RegisterAsyncService getRegisterAsyncService(final ServletContext servletContext) {
        final WebApplicationContext ctx = getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        final RegisterAsyncService registerAsyncService = Objects.requireNonNull(ctx).getBean(RegisterAsyncService.class);
        registerAsyncService.exec();
        return registerAsyncService;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer(CustomAnnotationIntrospector customAnnotationIntrospector) {
        return builder -> builder.serializationInclusion(NON_NULL)
            .annotationIntrospector(customAnnotationIntrospector);
    }
}
```

Ok.
So... I get the `date` field in response as:

```
2021-10-21T23:59:59.999999999-18:00
```

When i test my controller, i try to get response, deserialize it to `Request` object and check matching:

```
@DirtiesContext
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = {WebConfiguration.class, JacksonAutoConfiguration.class},
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableWebMvc
class RequestControllerTest {

    private static final CharacterEncodingFilter 
    CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER = new CharacterEncodingFilter();

    static {
        CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER.setEncoding(DEFAULT_ENCODING);
        CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER.setForceEncoding(true);
    }

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        this.mockMvc =
            MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                .addFilters(CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    void requestByIdTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/requests")
                .characterEncoding(CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(
                result -> Assertions.assertEquals(mapToObject(result.getResponse().getContentAsString(Charset.forName(CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER)), Request.class), getExpectedRequest()));
    }

    private WebComplianceRequest getExpectedRequest() {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.OCTOBER, 22);
        OffsetDateTime dateTime = date.atTime(OffsetTime.MAX);
        Request request = new Request(dateTime);
    }

    private <T> T mapToObject(String json, Class<T> targetClass) {
        try {
            return getReaderForClass(targetClass).readValue(json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeExsception(e);
        }
    }

    private <T> ObjectReader getReaderForClass(Class<T> targetClass) {
        return objectMapper.readerFor(targetClass);
    }
}
```

But i get a exception, because `date` field in expected object and in got object are differ:

```
Date in response: 2021-10-22T17:59:59.999999999Z
Expected date:    2021-10-21T23:59:59.999999999-18:00
```

Why did this happen?

Why does the `Z` appear instead of time zone? Why is the date changed from `2021-10-21` to `2021-10-22`? And how would i can fix it?

I do not get any exception, I get *matching failed* because dates differ when I match response and expected objects. I just deserialize object with standard `ObjectMapper` and check objects matching with `equals()`.

Comment: Post the code the outputs the above outputs so we can reproduce. See [mcve]

Comment: Well, `2021-10-21T23:59:59.999999999-18:00` has an offset of `-18:00` hours from UTC while `2021-10-22T17:59:59.999999999Z` is the same `Instant` in UTC (`Z` means *Zulu* / *UTC*). The difference between those is 18 hours. **You have two different representations (offsets) for the same moment in time**.

Comment: @deHaar but why days are differ?

Comment: The question needs to include the code you wrote to serialize this thing into JSON (presumably, as you tagged it with it, with Jackson), and how you deserialize it.

Comment: I think it would be important to see how are you serializing/deserializing. Also, i am not sure if the code that you posted compiles successfully. it should be date.atTime(OffsetTime.MAX);

Comment: You have the date and time `2021-10-21T23:59:59.999999999` which you define to be at an offset of `-18:00` (by `atTime(OffsetTime.MAX`). That means you basically have to *add* 18 hours in order to get the representation of the same moment in UTC (with an offset of `+00:00` or just `Z`) which results in a different day because the moment before midnight gets 18 hours added, which will turn to a time of next day.

Comment: @OleV.V. Or we could close and delete an incomplete question with inconsistent code sample.

Comment: @OleV.V. I have answered, but I somehow also agree with the above comment about closing incomplete questions.

Comment: Thanks for adding details, but: Where in your code do you get an `Exception`? Which line? Which `Exception`? Do you have error messages? Do you have influence on the value returned? If yes, you could just change the formatting from UTC to `-18:00`.

Comment: @deHaar i does not get exception, i get matching failed because dates differ when i match response and expected objects

Comment: How are you using the date from the response? Do you parse it with `OffsetDateTime.parse()` or does any mapper do that for you? Do you get it as `String`? If yes, you may want to adjust the offset (which automatically adjusts the values of hours, minutes and possibly days), like `String e = OffsetDateTime.parse(resultFromResponse).withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.MIN).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);`

Comment: @deHaar no, i just deserilize object with standard ObjectMapper and check objects matching with equals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What we know so far

1. You are creating an `OffsetDateTime` from a `LocalDate` adding the maximum offset available (which happens to be `-18:00` hours)
2. this `OffsetDateTime` gets correctly serialized to a JSON value of `2021-10-21T23:59:59.999999999-18:00`
3. when deserialized, the value (as `String`) is `2021-10-22T17:59:59.999999999Z`

The critical part is not included so far: *What happens between 2. and 3.?*
Please consider updating your question with everything you know about it.

### What we can derive

The values that appear incongruent are basically the same moment in time (`Instant`), but represented at an offset of `-18:00` at serialization and represented in UTC (`+00:00` or simply `Z`). Due to a difference of 18 hours between those moments and due to the fact you created an `OffsetDateTime` with `OffsetTime.MAX` (which is `23:59:59.999999999-18:00`, the maximum time of day at an offset of `-18:00`).

That's why the result you get after deserialization is **not wrong**, but its representation may not be the desired one.

My guess is that an `Instant` is used at the sub-steps between 2. and 3. and the deserialization simply provides date and time in UTC only.

I wouldn't pass any time with a maximum offset to any API if it is not explicitly required. Is it in your situation? Consider adding information about that, too.

### What we can do to make the time `String`s equal

You can use a different possibility of creating the `OffsetDateTime` from the `LocalDate`, that is using the maximum time of day without an offset explicitly at UTC:

```java
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(date, LocalTime.MAX, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

This would serialize to `2021-10-21T23:59:59.999999999Z`, you could also represent it as `2021-10-21T23:59:59.999999999+00:00` or similar (I would stick to `Z`) and deserialization ***should*** return the same value.

---

In case you receive a `String` representation in UTC and you don't have any influence on it, you will have to parse it and change the representation by applying the minimum offset (`-18:00`), maybe like this:

```java
String atMinOffset = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-22T17:59:59.999999999Z")
                                   .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.MIN)
                                   .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println(atMinOffset);
```

Output:

```
2021-10-21T23:59:59.999999999-18:00
```

---

In case you get an `OffsetDateTime` as a response and just want to check if it is the same point in time, consider this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    OffsetDateTime utcOdt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-22T17:59:59.999999999Z");
    OffsetDateTime minOffsetOdt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-10-21T23:59:59.999999999-18:00");
    
    System.out.println("OffsetDateTimes equal? --> " + utcOdt.equals(minOffsetOdt));
    System.out.println("Instants equal? --> " + utcOdt.toInstant().equals(minOffsetOdt.toInstant()));
}
```

It's output is

```
OffsetDateTimes equal? --> false
Instants equal? --> true
```

**Why?**
An `OffsetDateTime` is a *representation* of a moment in time while an `Instant` actually *is* that moment in time.
That means you should compare the real moment in time instead of context-based representations of it.

Comment: I add some details. Would you can read my question one more time, please?

Comment: @Zhenyria Please see my edits.